# Transform an integral to the Fourier sapce

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

Can I transform this integral $\int\int dx dy f(x) g(x,y) f(y)$ into the Fourier space? I am expecting something like  $\int\int dk dk'f(k)g(k,k')f(k') $, although I can't prove they are equivalent.

Note: $f(k)$ is the Fourier transform of  $ f(x)$. $g(k,k') $ is the Fourier transform of $ g(x,y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we use the unitary Fourier transform,
\begin{multline}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x)dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\!\!\!\int\!\!\!\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(k)G(k')e^{i(k+k')x}dk\,dk'\,dx 
\\ =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\!\!\!\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(k)G(k')\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(k+k')x}dx\right]\,dk\,dk' 
\\= \int\!\!\!\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(k)G(k')\delta(k+k')dk\,dk' = \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(k)G(-k)dk
\end{multline}
So, generalizing this to your double integral gives
$$
\int\!\!\!\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x,y)f(y)dx\,dy = \int\!\!\!\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(k)G(-k,-k')F(k')dk\,dk'
$$

Comment: I went through a longer derivation with the actual double integral and properties of the 2D Fourier Transform and came up with the same answer, assuming the original limits of integration were $\pm \infty$.  If they aren't, one can throw in some appropriately stretched boxcar functions to account for the limits of integration and perform a slightly more involved derivation.

Comment: @AndyWalls No need to go through the double integral. Separate into $\int f(x)\int g(x,y) f(y) dy\, dx$ and apply the single integral formula twice.

Comment: Interesting.  What I really did was set $p(t, \tau)= f(t)f(\tau)$ and $q(-t,-\tau)=g(t,\tau)$ so the double integral looked like the 2D convolution $r(t,\tau) = p * q$ evaluated at $r(0,0)$.  I then used 2D Fourier transforms & theorems from there.  Definitely the long way compared to your approach.